# Python doing multiple iterations on the same row

Tags: python, function, sqlite, iteration

I want to iterate rows from SQLite table and the code is working, however it runs the function 4 times before moving to the next row.

```
def get_ship_tm_window():
    # connect to database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('PSC.sdb')
    # create cursor
    c = conn.cursor()
    f = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM 'inspections tm'")
    conn.commit()
    with requests.Session() as s:
        for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM ships ORDER BY ISM"):
            print(row)
            ship_imo = row[1]
            print(ship_imo)
            get_tm_windows_access(s, ship_imo)
            f.execute(
                "INSERT INTO 'inspections tm' VALUES(:name, :imoship, :lastinsp, :ship_risk, :date_pii , :date_pi, :prio)",
                {
                    'name': row[0],
                    'imoship': row[1],
                    'lastinsp': '',
                    'ship_risk': get_tm_windows_access(s, ship_imo)[0],
                    'date_pii': get_tm_windows_access(s, ship_imo)[2],
                    'date_pi': get_tm_windows_access(s, ship_imo)[3],
                    'prio': get_tm_windows_access(s, ship_imo)[1]
                })
            conn.commit()
    conn.close()


get_ship_tm_window()
```

The result is:

```
('HANNA OLDENDORFF', 9731614, 'Anglo-Eastern (Germany) GmbH', 5365996, 'High', 'High') # prints row OK
9731614 #prints imo OK
7B9E9C8F-EAF8-46FA-A09E-6B852A5C7F4C #1ST TIME
High Risk Ship #1ST TIME
Priority I #1ST TIME
05/09/2019 #1ST TIME
05/11/2019 #1ST TIME
7B9E9C8F-EAF8-46FA-A09E-6B852A5C7F4C #2nd time
High Risk Ship #2nd time
Priority I #2nd time
05/09/2019 #2nd time
05/11/2019 #2nd time
7B9E9C8F-EAF8-46FA-A09E-6B852A5C7F4C #3RD TIME
High Risk Ship #3RD TIME
Priority I #3RD TIME
05/09/2019 #3RD TIME
05/11/2019 #3RD TIME
7B9E9C8F-EAF8-46FA-A09E-6B852A5C7F4C #4th time
High Risk Ship #4th time
Priority I #4th time
05/09/2019 #4th time
05/11/2019 #4th time
```

Here is should stop, but I get it 3 more times until it prints the new row. After the 4th time, it moves to the next row.

EDITED.

```
def get_tm_windows_access(s, ship_imo):
    date_from = datetime.now() - relativedelta(months=36)
    date_to = datetime.now()

    header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.',
              'Cookies': 'PHPSESSID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'}
    s.headers.update(header)
    r = s.get('https://apcis.tmou.org/public/')
    str_number = re.findall("<span[^>]+(.*?)</span>", r.text)[0]
    numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', str_number)
    captcha = int(numbers[0]) + int(numbers[1])
    payload = {'captcha': captcha}
    r = s.post('https://apcis.tmou.org/public/?action=login', data=payload)
    check_text = re.findall('<b>(.*?)</b>', r.text)[0]
    payload1 = {'Param': 0, 'Value': ship_imo, 'imo': ship_imo, 'callsign': '', 'name': '', 'compimo': '',
                'compname': '', 'From': date_from.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'), 'Till': date_to.strftime('%d.%m.%Y'),
                'authority': 0, 'flag': 0, 'class': 0, 'ro': 0, 'type': 0, 'result': 0, 'insptype': -1, 'sort1': 0,
                'sort2': 'DESC', 'sort3': 0,
                'sort4': 'DESC'
                }
    r = s.post('https://apcis.tmou.org/public/?action=getships', data=payload1)
    try:
        acces_code = re.findall('<input type="hidden" value="([^>]*)"/>', r.text)[0]
        print(acces_code)
        payload2 = {'HUID': acces_code}
        r = s.post('https://apcis.tmou.org/public/?action=getship', data=payload2)
        try:
            ship_risk = re.findall('<h2>(.*?), (.*?)</h2>', r.text)[0][0]
            ship_prio = re.findall('<h2>(.*?), (.*?)</h2>', r.text)[0][1]
            ship_window_raw = re.findall('<h2 class="winInspRange">Window Inspection Range:\n\n(.*?)</h2>', r.text)[0]
            ship_window_numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', ship_window_raw)
            pII = ship_window_numbers[0] + '/' + ship_window_numbers[1] + '/' + ship_window_numbers[2]
            pI = ship_window_numbers[3] + '/' + ship_window_numbers[4] + '/' + ship_window_numbers[5]
            return ship_risk, ship_prio, pII, pI
        except IndexError:
            ship_risk = re.findall('<h2>(.*?), (.*?)</h2>', r.text)[0][0]
            ship_prio = re.findall('<h2>(.*?), (.*?)</h2>', r.text)[0][1]
            pII = ''
            pI = ''
            return ship_risk, ship_prio, pII, pI
    except IndexError:
        return '', '', '', ''
```

Here you have the remaining of the code.
It is very strange for me that it runs 4 times.

Comment: Have you tried using just one cursor?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I have... same result.

Comment: Then there must be repeated data in the table.

Comment: No repeated data in the table. the iteration is correct it just repeats more than it should.

Comment: In that case please provide a [mre] with standalone code and data that reliably reproduces the error.

Comment: Please show definition of `get_tm_windows_access`, likely the reason since it is called four times.

Comment: What is the problem again? There is a `print` call in `get_tm_windows_access` which you call 5 times in `get_ship_tm_window`? Altogether you `print` 7 times (if no error emrges) in each iteration of loop which is the number of lines you post.

Comment: Do you agree that it should print only one time the access code. That is not happening. Every single row iteration repeats the function 4 times. I will edit to original output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid multiple calls to your other function, `get_tm_windows_access()`, by assigning result to a named variable then index this tuple for query parameters. Currently, you do not assign the first call to anything, so it runs with printed lines as you show but its returned output is not saved anywhere. Simply have that output saved to a variable.

```
def get_ship_tm_window():
    # connect to database
    conn = sqlite3.connect('PSC.sdb')

    # create cursor
    c = conn.cursor()
    f = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("DELETE FROM 'inspections tm'")
    conn.commit()

    with requests.Session() as s:
        for row in c.execute("SELECT * FROM ships ORDER BY ISM"):
            print(row)
            ship_imo = row[1]
            print(ship_imo)

            access_data = get_tm_windows_access(s, ship_imo)   # ADJUSTED LINE
            f.execute(
                "INSERT INTO 'inspections tm' VALUES(:name, :imoship, :lastinsp, :ship_risk, :date_pii , :date_pi, :prio)",
                {
                    'name': row[0],
                    'imoship': row[1],
                    'lastinsp': '',
                    'ship_risk': access_data[0],               # ADJUSTED LINE
                    'date_pii': access_data[2],                # ADJUSTED LINE
                    'date_pi': access_data[3],                 # ADJUSTED LINE
                    'prio': access_data[1]                     # ADJUSTED LINE
                })
            conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have learned it the hard way. Was really struggling but I understood the source of the issue and makes all sense! Thanks again!

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Also, you may be running Python in interactive mode (depending on IDE) where calling function on it's own line dumps the returned output, hence why you see contents with each call to other method.

Comment: I am using Pycharm. I actually trying to learn Python! :D